# SAML 2.0 support with WCF service

Tags: wcf, saml-2.0

I need to pass SAML token 2.0 ( issued by STS service) in WCF service. This WCF service does not use SAML token but just pass it to next service it is calling. How should I pass this. I can not use WIF since I am running Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need WIF on the client. WCF supports federated authentication.

You cannot pass the token for Service1 to Service2:

Client --> Service 1 --> Service 2

Service1 must obtain a token for Service2 from the STS using Token1 as the input. Search for "ActAs" scenarios.